# Android: add borders to ListView Items

Tags: java, android, listview

How can we add custom borders around ListView Items in android.

I know I can use dividers with a custom drawable background but it does not add it for the first and last element and therefore if there is only 1 item in the list, it won't even display it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are two xml-attributes called [footerDividersEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3afooterDividersEnabled) and [headerDividersEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3aheaderDividersEnabled)

and they have their corresponding java methods setFooterDividersEnabled and setHeaderDividerseEnabled.

Hope this solves your problem!